# How to convert datetime output datetime.datetime to datetime?

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote the following code and it gives output of current time in format `datetime.datetime.('current date and time')` , But i want output to be as `datetime('current date and time')`.

I want to remove preceding **"Datetime"** , tried it with "**split"** but its not working ,gives the following error  `"datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split"`.

does anyone know how to do it in python?

thanks in advance.

```
{

from datetime import datetime
test = datetime.now()
test.split('.')[0]

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `split` will only work on a String not `datetime.datetime`. Here this will clear  out your confusion -

```
hussain@work-desktop:~$ python
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Sep 27 2012, 21:16:52) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> test = datetime.now()
>>> print test
2013-10-23 11:49:28.385757
>>> test.split('.')[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'
>>> type(test)
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> test.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2013-10-23 11:49:28'
```

Comment: ok thanks but can you tell me how should i get output format as datetime.(2013, 10, 23, 12, 17, 8, 831917) instead of datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 23, 12, 17, 8, 831917)

Comment: You mean you want a python tuple - (2013, 10, 23, 12, 17, 8, 831917) ?

Comment: If Yes then do `tuple(test.strftime('%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S,%s').split(','))` and you will get above tuple.

Comment: If this is what you were looking for then You can click - `click to accept this answer` just below answer's reputation and accept the answer.